# Tableau on Splunk.. Possible?

Tags: business-intelligence, splunk, tableau-api

My BI team would like to access my Splunk data using Tableau, we don't want to use Splunk visualizations and would rather use our BI tools...

We tried to use Splunk connectors but that failed and the volume of data is too big to show on tableau... is there any solution for this problem ? how can that be achieved and what are your recommnendations on this subject?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. this is possible. You can use splunk SDK. By using this you and bring your data and feed it into tableau.

We are using this thing with QlickSense